# How to avoid all widget rebuild with setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a border to a container starts scrolling down and remove it if scrolled back to the top.

I am listening to the scroll controller and setting the state with setState() however looks like the whole widget is being rebuilt you can see the glitch.

Can someone help on how to fix that? I added comments on border and listview for the shortcut:

the class:

```
class __ExampleAlertDialogState extends State<_ExampleAlertDialog> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  var scrollPos = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 20),
      child: Expanded(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          child: Material(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      
                      // Adding and removing the border here

                      border: Border(
                          bottom: scrollPos == true
                              ? BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor)
                              : BorderSide.none)),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 12),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [Icon(Icons.arrow_back), Icon(Icons.refresh)],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(

                  // This is the scrollable ListView

                    child: ListView.builder(
                     controller: _scrollController,
                     ...
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    if (currentScroll > 2 && scrollPos == false) {
      setState(() {
        scrollPos = true;
      });
    } else if(currentScroll < 2 && scrollPos == true) {
      setState(() {
        scrollPos = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can refractor the widget that need build alone in a class or use a state management solution (provider for example).

Comment: hoped it would be easier than that but let me try that @MohammedAlfateh

Comment: that is how its done in flutter, you refactor it into a seperate standalone stateful widget